# Exponential Equation $4\cdot7^{x+2}=9^{2x-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Let $4\cdot7^{x+2}=9^{2x-3}.$

I do not know how to solve for $x$.

#### Progress

Took logarithms, got
$$4(x+2\log7)=(2x-3)\log9$$ $$(x+2)\log7=[(2x-3)\log9]/4$$

Comment: what did you try to do?

Comment: Do you mean $4(7^x + 2) = 9^{2x}-3$ or $4(7^{x+2}) = 9^{2x-3}$?

Comment: 4(x+2log7)=(2x-3)log9 and (x+2)log7=[(2x-3)log9]/4

Comment: @SRX The second one. Sorry!

Comment: I've edited your question @Rui.

Comment: Without work -> http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%287%5E%28x%2B2%29%29%3D9%5E%282x%E2%88%923%29

Comment: @Rui The equations are inconsistent. Is the L.H.S. $4(x+2 \log 7)$ or $4(x+2)\log 7$? Also in either case the L.H.S. of the original question you pose should have the $4$ on the exponent but not as a multiple of $7^{x+2}$.

Comment: @SRX That is what I tried. The answer in the back of the textbook is 4.85. Thank-you for your help!

Comment: @SRX The original question is the second one from your first comment.

Comment: @Rui, Could you accept the edition that I did with the right equation?

Comment: @Alex Silva Thank-you for the edit but that is not the question in the textbook.

Comment: @Rui, Yes, It is.

Comment: @SRX Thank-you!

Comment: @Rui Welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clarified that we are to solve $4(7^{x+2}) = 9^{2x-3}$. Taking $\log$ is the right process but you have to make sure you do it right.

Using $\log(ab) = \log(a) + \log(b)$, the L.H.S. should be $\log 4 + (x+2) \log 7$ but not $4(x + 2) \log 7$.

Hence we have

\begin{align}
\log 4 + (x+2) \log 7 & = (2x - 3) \log 9 \\
(\log 7)x + (\log 4 + 2\log 7) & = (2\log 9) x - 3 \log 9 \\
(2\log 9- \log 7)x & = \log 4 + 2\log 7 + 3 \log 9 \\
x & = \frac{\log 4 + 2\log 7 + 3 \log 9}{2\log 9- \log 7}
\end{align}

Comment: Your RHS isn't quite right, it should be log(4) + (x + 2)log(7)

Comment: I start from the question provided in the comment, and the equations are inconsistent with the one originally posed.

Answer (score 0):

$$4 \times {7^{x + 2}} = {9^{2x - 3}} \Leftrightarrow 4 \times 49 \times {7^x} = \frac{{{{81}^x}}}
{{729}} \Leftrightarrow {\left( {\frac{{81}}
{7}} \right)^x} = 4 \times 49 \times 729 = 142884 \Leftrightarrow x = {\log _{81/7}}142884.$$